# D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null when decoding from base64 to bitmap

Tags: android, json, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Hiii
        In doInBackground Iam fetching image(base64) from server.here is the code and parsing from JSON

```
 JSONArray array=jobj.getJSONArray("values");

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                imgString=obj.getString("image");
            }
```

But when i decode base64 to bitmap it says "D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null"
    here is the code for decode64

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object o)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        decodeBase64(imgString);

    }


    public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodeBytes= android.util.Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_PADDING);

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeBytes,0,decodeBytes.length);
}
```

Please help to solve this..thank you

Comment: What is the resolution of the image? Please calculate WxHx4.

Comment: `decodeBytes`. How many bytes? Save them to file and use a photo viewer to see the image.

Comment: I put try n catch in method decodeBase64 which solved my problem

Comment: That can never solve a problem. Only prevent a crash. And dont you want to know why a `null` was returned?

Comment: sure i do @greenapps